# View moves down when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicontainerview

I'm building an iPad app and there is something weird going on with the top edge of the view in relation to the status bar when the keyboard appears.

The view has a view with a segmented controller at the top with a container view below. When a button in the segmented controller is selected, the view in the container view changes.

I've done some research into the matter (it's definitely iOS 7 related) and have not found any kind of fix. I tried setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdgeNone` but that does not seem to have any effect. Even more strange, the view only moves half way to its original position when the keyboard dismisses. Any suggestions? I included screenshots below.

Original:
[image: Original]

When keyboard appears:
[image: Keyboard Appears]

After keyboard dismisses:
[image: Keyboard Dismissed]

Comment: Is it on simulator or on a device ?

Comment: Are you doing anything during keyboard notifications? If you are, can you post that code?

Comment: It's on both the simulator and my iPad.

Comment: I'm not doing anything on the keyboard notifications either.

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController or your own custom view controller? Your main view might have ambiguous constraints, so it is shifting around during the animation.

Comment: It's a custom view controller.

Comment: Uhm, is the entire view just a UIWebView?

Comment: it would help if you posted the code that handles keyboard appearance

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume your code is doing something to move the view when the keyboard appears then later disappears. So you state your view is a UIViewcontroller subclass (implying no contentOffset property). Log the values of the following before and after the keyboard action - one of them must have changed: contentInset, bounds, frame. Knowing which one will assist you in finding the problem.